# Convert Perl regex expression to Java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to convert http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/DSTAAL/Mail-Log-Parse-1.0400/lib/Mail/Log/Parse/Postfix.pm to Java.

Given the perl code snippet

```
@{$line_info{to}} = $line_info{text} =~ m/\bto=([^,]+),/g;
```

Which equates to java pseudocode

```
if (lineInfo.getText().contains("<beginning of word or sentence>to=")) {
    lineInfo.setTo(lineInfo.getText().<get text between 'to=' and comma?>);
}
```

Could anyone give me a working Java example?

An example input line might be

```
Apr 22 07:08:33 server postfix/smtpd[19793]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from mail-eopbgr50060.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.107.5.60]: <someone@something.co.uk>: Sender address triggers FILTER smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024; from=<someone@something.co.uk> to=<someone2@something2.co.uk> proto=ESMTP helo=<EUR03-VE1-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com>
```

and I would expect `lineInfo.setTo()` to be set to `someone2@something2.co.uk`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the text of the capture group, you need to use the [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) classes.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bto=([^,]+),"); // remember to double the \ escape
Matcher m = p.matcher(lineInfo.getText());
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    list.add(m.group(1)); // add text in capture group 1 to the list
}
lineInfo.setTo(list);
```

As a single statement, in Java 9+, you can use streams:

```
lineInfo.setTo(Pattern.compile("\\bto=([^,]+),")
                      .matcher(lineInfo.getText())
                      .results()
                      .map(r -> r.group(1))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: yes this works.  i tried it before and couldn't get it to work.  then figured out the double slash thing after your first answer.  thanks

Comment: is it important to pre compile the pattern for reuse in a batch processing application?

Comment: @MitchBroadhead Depends. Only performance testing can show you how important it might be in your case. If it is easy to move the `compile` outside a loop, then do so, but don't jump through too many hoops for it. Premature optimization and all.